# Auto-generate .pxd file with pyrobuf for faster calls in cython function

Tags: protocol-buffers, cython, openstreetmap, osm.pbf

## Context

I would like to speedup a cython function where I read an osm.pbf file via [`pyrosm`](https://github.com/HTenkanen/pyrosm).

In this library, the file is read via [`pyrobuf` prototypes](https://github.com/HTenkanen/pyrosm/blob/master/proto/fileformat.proto): [`pyrobuf`](https://github.com/appnexus/pyrobuf) generates a .c file with the relevant classes and their `ParseFromString` functions.

However, in the .pyx file, these classes are [imported via python](https://github.com/HTenkanen/pyrosm/blob/master/pyrosm/pbfreader.pyx#L4), which (I imagine), slows things down when they are called (repeatedly, within a loop).

## Question(s)

Is there a way to tell pyrobuf to generate a .pxd file associated to the .c file so I can cimport everything?
If not, is there a simple way to autogenerate a .pxd from a random .c file?

Comment: This will not answer your question directly, but it seems pyrosm has fallen asleep as there is no activity for more than one year by now. Take a look at https://pyogrio.readthedocs.io instead to import osm.pbf files..